# N-Well Resistor

Tags: microprocessor, semiconductors, vlsi

So as I'm currently looking into basic VSLI, I made a simple voltage divider in Electric using N-Well resistors. I was hoping to understand: Why does an N-well act as a resistor? A reference to better information than I'm currently receiving would suffice.

Additionally, I was wondering if the resistance would be a factor of depth or concentration of the n-well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any diffusion into the silicon can be used to make a resistor, but the N-well is often used because it has a much higher resistance per square as compared to the source/drain diffusions. Yes, the resistance is a function of both depth and concentration. Increasing concentration or depth will decrease the sheet resistance of the well, all other factors being unchanged.